# Position in fullscreen mode not working on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fullscreen

I have implemented [fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) on the site: http://nietkow.com (Just click on "Pantalla Completa / Pełny Ekran")

With these rules I have got the gallery centered on the screen in Chrome but not in Firefox:

```
.ad-image-wrapper:-webkit-full-screen {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    background-color: black;
}

.ad-image-wrapper:-moz-full-screen {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

I have tried using different combinations and nothing seems to work. I can easily change the background color but not the position.

Is not clear to me what element is the parent in fullscreen mode and what rules apply to style both.

Comment: [Note that Firefox renders your gallery div as fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Presentation_differences). So I you probably need a container div around your gallery.

Comment: I don't know, but the MDN page says if you want WebKit to behave the same as Gecko, you'll need to add `width:100%; height:100%` to the style for the ad-image-wrapper in fullscreen. And sure enough, then it does behave like Gecko. This is not what you want, obviously, but maybe you can take it from there.

Comment: By the way, my adblocker mistrusts anything that starts with "ad-". Are you sure those are good class names? Also, I have never seen a site that is in Spanish and Polish.